# Adding objects to the generic list

Tags: java, list, generics

Hi I am trying to add same object with different property settings. But When Iterate through the List it gives me latest added Setting.

As you can see below is my code.

```
List<TestObject> list = new ArrayList<TestObject>();
TestObject  t= new TestObject();
t.setEmail("John1989@gmail.com");
list.add(t);
System.out.println(list.get(0).getEmail());
t.setEmail("The_lawyer99yahoo.com");
list.add(t);
System.out.println(list.get(1).getEmail());

for(TestObject s : list)
{
    System.out.println(s.getEmail());
}
```

Output:

```
John1989@gmail.com
The_lawyer99yahoo.com
The_lawyer99yahoo.com
The_lawyer99yahoo.com
```

What my doubt is why iteretor is giving latest added Object seting (email) But When I excute this statement `System.out.println(list.get(0).getEmail());` its working fine

Why is `for` loop just keep returning with recently added object ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not creating a new object, but simply changing properties of the same object in memory.  `List` will allow you to add the same instance of a `Object` multiple times, so it can "look" like you've added multiple objects when in fact, it's just a bunch of elements pointing to the same object.  Use a `Set` of some kind instead and you will find you only have a single object ;)

Comment: you have the same objet t, so is the same reference, you have to make a new one before set the 2 email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess Java only places a reference to the object into your list so as youre changing the properties of your element it affects the list contents as well.

Answer (score 3):

You're not creating a new object, but simply changing properties of the same object in memory.  `List` will allow you to add the same instance of a `Object` multiple times, so it can "look" like you've added multiple objects when in fact, it's just a bunch of elements pointing to the same object.  Use a `Set` of some kind instead and you will find you only have a single object ;)

You would need to create a new instance of the `TestObject` for each new entry, for example...

```
List<TestObject> list = new ArrayList<TestObject>();
TestObject  t= new TestObject();
t.setEmail("John1989@gmail.com");
list.add(t);
System.out.println(list.get(0).getEmail());

t= new TestObject();
t.setEmail("The_lawyer99yahoo.com");
list.add(t);
System.out.println(list.get(1).getEmail());

for(TestObject s : list)
{
   System.out.println(s.getEmail());
}
```

This way, the properties are associated with a different instance of the `TestObject` for each entry

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is called aliasing. When you submit your object `t` to the container, it's actually interested in the reference of your object. Because of that, the item at position 0 and the one at position 1 are exactly the same, because you stored the same reference at the same object twice instead of two different objects. Thus when you modify `t` you are actually modifying the sole object created till now, and both the references will show the updated date.

To solve it, simply create a new object and add it to the list by using the following line (as you already do the first time):

```
t = new TestObject();
```